# Get all strings between two chars in a string

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string like this:

> {abc}@{defgh}mner{123}

How can I get all strings between `{` and `}` as an array or list?

Like this:

`{ {abc},{defgh},{123} }`

Comment: Have you tried something already? There's a couple of ways to do this

Comment: Using regular expressions with capturing groups

Comment: yes, i write a loop for get strings between { and }, but it is not best way. @shree.pat18

Comment: Is this possible `{abc}}}@{defgh}mner{123}`? Or this `asd{asd`?

Comment: @radin how do you know loop is not the best way? Post your code so we can tell you. Also tell us what is “best” for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get values between curly braces c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379482/get-values-between-curly-braces-c-sharp) and [many others](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+c%23+get+text+between+brackets).

Comment: @FCin Yes, is possible.

Comment: @CaiusJard i did this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780654/extract-all-strings-between-two-strings). but my string is different. `{asd{asd}dd}34{wqw}`

Comment: Yeah, I think that edit you made will invalidate a lot of answers here. We also can't post any more answers because this question is closed as a duplicate. Ask a new question, and put the edited version; {a{b}c}d{e} is very different requirement to {a}b{c}d{e} and probably requires a loop that counts the braces and only emits a text when the count becomes 0

Comment: @CaiusJard Ok, Thank you.

Comment: @BACON I Edit this question, please check it.

Comment: @radin this question has been **closed** as a duplicate, which your original question was. The new addition changes the scope of the question and as such it's better if you simply open a new one (in general). In this particular case, this question here answers your exact need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778532/regular-expression-to-match-nested-braces

Answer (score 2):

using Regex is a good choice

```
    string str = "{abc}@{defgh}mner{123}";
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str,"{[^}]+}"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sites like RegExr, you can easily try your regex before using it in code:

```
string str = "{abc}@{defgh}mner{123}";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str,"(\{.+?\})"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

https://regexr.com/460a3

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code, it doesn't uses regular expressions, so you don't need to know it!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string s = "{abc}@{defgh}mner{123}";
  int i1, i2 = 0;
  while ((i1 = s.IndexOf('{', i2)) >= 0)
  {
    i2 = s.IndexOf('}', i1);
    // Here you can add Substring result to some list or assign it to a variable...
    Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(i1 + 1, i2 - i1 - 1));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "{abc}@{defgh}mner{123}";
var pattern = @"\{(.+?)\}";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
IList<string> output = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in matches)
    output.Add(match.Groups[0].Value);
```

[Fiddle Result](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jr8SX1)

---

Simple Version

```
var input = "{abc}@{defgh}mner{123}";
var pattern = @"\{(.+?)\}";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
IList<string> output = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[0].Value).ToList();           
output.Dump();
```

[Fiddle Result](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XeAeQB)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex

```
var str = "{abc}@{defgh}mner{123}";
var regex = new Regex(@"({\w+})",RegexOptions.Compiled);
var result = regex.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value);
```

result is `IEnumerable<string>` as required in OP

Output (value of Result)

```
{abc} 
{defgh} 
{123}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex and turning them into a list using LINQ

```
var l = new Regex(@"\{(\w+)\}")
        .Matches("{abc}@{defgh}mner{123}l")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
        .ToList();
```

How it works:

The regex {(\w+)} means:

- {: Find a {
- (: start capturing data group
- \w+: match one or more word characters (a to z, 0 to 9)
- ): end of capture
- ): find a }

This will find all the text between the curly brackets

The regex will give a MatchCollection

We have to use Cast to turn it into something linq can query

We .Select items from the collection, m is an individual item, m.Groups[0].Value is the text captured by the group, between the curly brackets

.ToList returns all the texts in one list

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
  public static void Main()
  {
   string pattern = @"{([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)}" ; 
   string input = "{abc}@{defgh}mner{123}";
   MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

   foreach (Match match in matches)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
   }
   Console.WriteLine();
  }
}
```

> **Output :**
>
> abc
>
> defgh
>
> 123

You can check the Online Execution of the code : 
http://tpcg.io/uuIxo1